# css trying to reproduce the grid example with flex

Tags: html, css

I made this example easily with CSS Grid. But I think it is impossible to reproduce via Flexbox, isn't it?

```css
.Message {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: ". name""date text";
}

.Date {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  grid-area: date;
}

.Name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.Text {
  grid-area: text;
}

.Date,
.Name,
.Text {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Message">
  <div class="Name">name</div>
  <div class="Date">date (vertically centered)</div>
  <div class="Text">three<br />line<br />text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could pretty much do it if the order of divs can be changed. (I sort of made it work, but wouldn't use flex for this.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with `width:max-content`, `justify-content:flex-end`, `margin`, `wrap` and `min-width` to mimic something very close:

example:

```css
.Message {
  margin: 1em;
  width: max-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end
}

.Name {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.Date {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.Date,
.Name,
.Text {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 3em; /* give them an average min-width to simulate a last column of same width . tune to your needs */
}
```

```html
<div class="Message">
  <div class="Name">name</div>
  <div class="Date">date (vertically centered)</div>
  <div class="Text">three<br />line<br />text</div>
</div>
```

**Its not because it looks okay, that it is to be used. grid and flex have different purposes and here grid is required** ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to achieve this exact layout with only flexbox, unless you move `.Date` and `.Text` elements into another container.

```css
.Message {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: end
}

.Break {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.Date {
  flex: 1 1 fit-content;
}

.Date,
.Name,
.Text {
  border: 1px solid maroon;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="Message">
  <div class="Name">name</div>
  <div class="Break">
    <div class="Date">date (vertically centered)</div>
    <div class="Text">three<br />line<br />text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it's still not exactly what you have now. So, yeah. You need grid for that.